# Парсинг Curl

Tags: curl, php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте, делаю парсинг некоторых данных, нужно скопировать все значения в следующем диве

```
<div class="desc"></div>
```

Делаю это так

```
preg_match('/<div class\=\"desc\"\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/s', $result, $desc);
```

Но парсинг натыкается на первый закрывающий тэг </div> и парсит не полноценное описание, как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match('#<div class="desc">(.*)</div>#sU', $result, $desc);
```

Помогло?
Если нет - покажите страницу.

Comment: Проверю завтра(на работе), если поможет отмечу ответ.

Comment: Не помогло, мне нужно описание от сюда http://gltw.ru/7qq, естественно див с классом desc я приводил как пример, в парсинге использовал настоящие значения.

Answer (score 2):

[Не пытаться](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/116546) описать язык с контекстно-зависимой грамматикой регулярным выражением.

Попробуйте использовать [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

Примеры использования можно найти в поисковике, их там тысячи. Например, [учимся парсить сайты с библиотекой PHP Simple HTML DOM Parse](http://xdan.ru/Uchimsya-parsit-saity-s-bibliotekoi-PHP-Simple-HTML-DOM-Parser.html).

Возможно удобнее будет использовать с оберткой типа [Нокогири: парсинг HTML в одну строку](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110112/).

Comment: мля, пока писал ответ, ты опередил :):):)

Comment: "HTML Tidy" + DOM - если нет желания связываться с чужими парсерами

Comment: Я обязательно начну парсить данными средствами после окончания парсинга регулярками, т.к. в данном проекте сделал уже работу  на 90%.

Answer (score 0):

Очень хороший, развернутый (и шедеврально популярный) ответ на ваш вопрос был дан **[тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)** (*stackoverflow*)

Коротко - "You can't parse [X]HTML with regex" перевод (если требуется) - "ты не можешь отпарсить XHTML с помощью regex", далее куча **весьма занятных** доводов и, как вывод, вопрос - "Have you tried using an XML parser instead?" т.е. "почему бы тебе не воспользоваться XML парсером?"