# Как получить с стороннего сайта css файл

Tags: php, javascript, css

Недавно возникла идея сделать проект. Его суть заключается в получении всех css файлов введённого пользователем сайта и дальнейшая работа с ними средствами PHP или javascript. Меня интересует как можно получить эти файлы. Как сказать программе чтобы на проверила сайт на папки "css", "styles" и соответственно взяла оттуда всё и скачала, например, в папочку "loaded files". Может есть какая-нибудь библиотека?

Comment: Просто сказать программе скачать все файлы из папки css и styles не сложно, но если сервер не даст список файлов, вот это вопрос.

Comment: Скачивайте index.php и все связанные с ней страницы, дальше с помощью регулярных выражений или простого поиска ищите <link rel="stylesheet" и выделяйте href. После получения Href вы сможете скачать нужный вам файл и продолжить работу с ним

Comment: @Saidolim Ну, список файлов  папке сервер и не даёт. Например, только что тестировал один сайт: на http://sitename.ru/css он выдаёт 403 ошибку, а на sitename.ru/css/styles.css он успешно открывает содержимое. Мне это и надо, чтобы программа искала именно в "css/styles.css ; styles/style.css" и т.д. Я и спрашиваю как это сделать. Какие библиотеки есть. Или как с помощью PHP это сделать

Comment: @KonstantinKulakov Спасибо, попробую. Как раз недавно практиковался в регулярных выражениях.

Comment: Стоп. Не рекомендую регулярные выражения для этого. Читайте [это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/146917/177613) и [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/176635/)

Comment: @tutankhamun Спасибо, попробую в этом разобраться.

Comment: @tutankhamun действительно, совершенно забыл про подходит описанный вами.

Comment: @Flaffen `wget -E -H -K -p -A "*.css" http://example.com` скачает все css которые упоминаются в index Но если надо со всего сайта то по хорошему надо вдобавок еще и по всем ссылкам пройтись, для этого у wget то же ключи найдутся